Rationale behind declaring FILE * volatile to stdin in C
I wonder what reason might be to declare FILE *volatile fp as volatile pointer:
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int gc;
  fe_Object *obj;
  FILE *volatile fp = stdin;
  fe_Context *ctx = fe_open(buf, sizeof(buf));

  /* init input file */
  if (argc > 1) {
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!fp) { fe_error(ctx, "could not open input file"); }
  }

  if (fp == stdin) { fe_handlers(ctx)->error = onerror; }
  gc = fe_savegc(ctx);
  setjmp(toplevel);

  /* re(p)l */
  for (;;) {
    fe_restoregc(ctx, gc);
    if (fp == stdin) { printf("> "); }
    if (!(obj = fe_readfp(ctx, fp))) { break; }
    obj = fe_eval(ctx, obj);
    if (fp == stdin) { fe_writefp(ctx, obj, stdout); printf("\n"); }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Source: https://github.com/rxi/fe/blob/ed4cda96bd582cbb08520964ba627efb40f3dd91/src/fe.c#L854
The pointer fp is not changing from hardware side or in interrupts by any means. It seems not changing in signal handlers either.
Projects seems to me as well written and I guess there's some reason behind that I can't understand. Please, provide some clues about that.

Did you ask the authors of that software? They should know.

Maybe there is no rationale. Programmers aren't always rational.

"The memory pointed by fp is not changing from hardware side" The memory pointed to by fp is not volatile. fp itself is volatile. Your title does not match the code you show. FILE volatile * is very different from FILE * volatile.

True, thanks for pointing to misleading phrase! Pointer is volatile itself and not the memory pointer refers to (e.g. struct FILE).

BTW: Your title still does not match the code in your question. You might want to fix that

Yep, thanks for mention it and thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/11294831/the-busybee for fixing that :)

I would guess that volatile is being used here for its interaction with setjmp/longjmp -- notice that there is a call to setjmp in main.  From the CAVEATS section of the setjmp manual page:

The compiler may optimize variables into registers, and longjmp() may restore the  values
of  other  registers in addition to the stack pointer and program counter.  Consequently,
the values of automatic variables are unspecified after a call to longjmp() if they  meet
all the following criteria:
•  they are local to the function that made the corresponding setjmp() call;
•  their values are changed between the calls to setjmp() and longjmp(); and
•  they are not declared as volatile.

Now in this code it does not appear that fp can be changed after the call to setjmp, unless one of the fe_ calls is actually a macro that modifies fp.  So it would appear that the volatile is actually unnecessary.
This is actually the most common use of volatile for a local (rather than global) variable.

Nice answer. This application of virtual was new to me (I do not remember having ever used setjmp/longjmp in serious code since I have always seen it as a dubious construction which this only confirms). It still seems strange to me that fp is declared virtual and e.g. obj is not.

FILE *volatile fp declares a volatile pointer (i.e. fp is volatile) to a FILE object (we do not know if that type is volatile or not). Hence, in this context volatile is needed if fp could potentially be changed by hardware or another thread/interrupt handler. However, this does not seem to be the case. fp is a local variable and its address is not passed to another function.
Thus the volatile declaration is not needed in this case.

There is a case where volatile is needed even though the object’s address is not passed and the object is not changed in a signal handler or by hardware: When you want to be able to change it in a debugger and be sure that change will be used and not be mooted because the compiler kept the value in a register or otherwise optimized. Maybe not the case here, but it is a possibility.

@EricPostpischil That is a good point. In that case, I would make the declaration in a way which made it clear that it was for debugging and not include it in the production build. In any case, volatile is not necessary for correct execution of the code here.
